# How can I export data from an array to an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

Sorry if tutorials for this already exist, but the only help I can find is much more advanced than for what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a 100 element array of integers that I want to export into a spreadsheet. Array[0] goes to A1, Array[2] goes to A2, etc.

I've downloaded JExcelAPI, but I can't follow the tutorials because the tool is for pretty advanced tasks.

Answer (score 0):

try Apache POI... http://poi.apache.org/
i believe this best API for creating microsoft office documents..
(Except MS Visio because you cannot create visio files with this API)

try this....

Comment: I'm having problems installing the API, as it's pretty new to me and I haven't done it before. How can I add it to my directory so I can import its files?

Comment: are you using any IDE ? if so add the jar file to build path...
check some Examples in the web...
i believe apache POI site have the examples...

Comment: I'm using JCreator. So I downloaded Apache POI, and I managed to add the jar files to the build path, but I don't know which files to import to accomplish this simple task, because there are so many.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use OpenXML or jexcel API, which is not as complicated as you are talking about it, consider using a simple .csv file. .csv are easily opened by Excel.
So what you would need is to write your integers to a file like this: 1;2;23;;4;5;5;1; and when it is opened in Excel, you'll get exactly what you need.